# Big query find data that could be in multiple columns

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with the following data

```
id|task1_name|task1_date|task2_name|task2_date
1,breakfast,1/1/20,,
2,null,null,breakfast,,1/1/20
3,null,null,lunch,,1/1/20
4,dinner,1/1/20,lunch,1/1/10
```

I'd like to build a view that always displayed the task names in the same column or null if it could not be found in any of the columns e.g.

```
id|dinner_date|lunch_date|breakfast_date
1,1/1/20, null, null
2,null, null, 1/1/20
2,1/1/20, 1/1/10, null
```

I've tried using a nested IF statement e.g.

```
SELECT *
IF(task_1_name = 'dinner', task1_date, IF(task2_date = 'dinner', task2_date, NULL)) as `dinner_date`
FROM t
```

But as there are 50 or so columns in the real dataset, this seems like a stupid solution and would get complex very quickly, is there a smarter way here?

Comment: when you say 50 columns - do you mean 'taskN_name' and 'taskN_date' columns with N up to 50?

Comment: @MikhailBerlyant yes, sorry for not being super clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses `case` expressions:

```
select t.*,
       (case when task1_name = 'dinner' then task1_date
             when task2_name = 'dinner' then task2_date
             when task3_name = 'dinner' then task3_date
        end) as dinner_date             
from t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Below is for BigQuery Standard SQL and generic enough to addresses concerns expressed in question. You don't need to know in advance number of columns and tasks names (although they should not have `,` or `:` which should not be a big limitation here and can be addressed if needed)

```
#standardSQL
CREATE TEMP TABLE ttt AS 
SELECT id, 
  SPLIT(k, '_')[OFFSET(0)] task, 
  MAX(IF(SPLIT(k, '_')[OFFSET(1)] = 'name', v, NULL)) AS name,
  MAX(IF(SPLIT(k, '_')[OFFSET(1)] = 'date', v, NULL)) AS DAY
FROM (
  SELECT id, 
    TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') k,
    TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)], '"') v
  FROM `project.dataset.table` t,
  UNNEST(SPLIT(TRIM(TO_JSON_STRING(t), '{}'))) kv
  WHERE TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(0)], '"') != 'id'
  AND TRIM(SPLIT(kv, ':')[OFFSET(1)], '"') != 'null'
)
GROUP BY id, task;

EXECUTE IMMEDIATE '''
SELECT id, ''' || (
  SELECT STRING_AGG(DISTINCT "MAX(IF(name = '" || name || "', day, NULL)) AS " || name || "_date")
  FROM ttt
) || '''  
FROM ttt
GROUP BY 1
ORDER BY 1
'''
```

Note; the assumption here is only about columns name to be `task<N>_name` and `task<N>_date`

If to apply to sample data (similar) to yours in question

```
WITH `project.dataset.table` AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'breakfast' task1_name, '1/1/21' task1_date, NULL task2_name, NULL task2_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL, NULL, 'breakfast', '1/1/22' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, 'lunch', '1/1/23' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'dinner', '1/1/24', 'lunch', '1/1/10'
)
```

output is

```
Row id  breakfast_date  lunch_date  dinner_date  
1   1   1/1/21          null        null     
2   2   1/1/22          null        null     
3   3   null            1/1/23      null     
4   4   null            1/1/10      1/1/24
```

Comment: Just to note that currently (in 2020) bigquery requires temp tables to created using a script https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/scripting

Comment: what you mean by above comment? it is a script!

Comment: Ah it was just a note to anyone else who just expected to be able to paste the query into the query editor in bigquery 

Answer (score 1):

Here is another solution which doesn't use dynamic SQL, doesn't rely on specific column names and works with arbitrary number of columns:

```
WITH table AS (
  SELECT 1 id, 'breakfast' task1_name, '1/1/21' task1_date, NULL task2_name, NULL task2_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, NULL, NULL, 'breakfast', '1/1/22' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, NULL, NULL, 'lunch', '1/1/23' UNION ALL
  SELECT 4, 'dinner', '1/1/24', 'lunch', '1/1/10'
)
SELECT 
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(f, r'breakfast\, ([^\,\)]*)'),
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(f, r'lunch\, ([^\,\)]*)'),
  REGEXP_EXTRACT(f, r'dinner\, ([^\,\)]*)')
FROM (
  SELECT FORMAT("%t", t) f FROM table t
)
```

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what SELECT FORMAT("%t", t) f FROM table t does? 

Comment: "FROM table t" makes "t" an alias to the row (which has STRUCT type). FORMAT element "%t" formats every data type into readable form, so here we are building string from the table row. And then parse it with REGEXP_EXTRACT